# iframe video is not playing in Android webview

Tags: javascript, android, iframe, webview

I have an issue with Android webview. I made android webview of this site http://www.drakor.co/. Youtube trailer's working fine but movie/video (other than youtube) is not working. Even thumbnail is not showing.

```html
<iframe src="//gdriveplayer.us/embed.php?hash=FKXhiwfju94OYt5C2NUeZD3qm" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="400" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable javascript of webview using

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```